# Enterprise application design for J2EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jms

For my own understanding of Java Enterprise Edition, i want to develop a small J2EE application like Amazon where use can order a product, product is purchased and delivered via courier where notifications are sent to client on shipment update. A small database that can store orders. I need to use J2EE components for this. Can i get an get an overview of the process? Like what components i need at which stage of this project. I am quite familiar with Java, but i haven't worked with enterprise applications yet.

**Update**:
I want to use J2EE components like JMS, EJB etc.

Comment: You're basically asking us to answer with what could fit in one or several books. Buy one.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following Java EE & Java technologies to accomplish your goal. The [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org) IDE is fairly easy to use and has a lot of support for Java EE. Others prefer Eclipse or IntelliJ. Here is a basic 4 layered architecture for a Java EE application:

**User Interface**: JSP (Java Server Pages) - They render to HTML/CSS for viewing in a web browser.

**Controllers**: Servlets - They receive incoming requests or form posts from your JSPs, process the requests and forward to result JSPs.

**Services**: EJBs - These are just regular Java classes that contain functionality (business logic) that is repeatedly used by your servlets (they are not used by your JSPs). They are marked up with annotations related to the roles as EJBs. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans#Reinventing_EJBs

**Data Access**: JPA -The java persistence API. You use this for storing and retrieving information from the database.

Other stuff:

**Messsage Oriented Middleware**: JMS - You can use JMS to communicate between system actors in an asynchronous fashion. For instance your courier's tracking system might communicate with the vendor's order system via JMS to update the status of the delivery. This would allow a loose coupling to accommodate multiple couriers.

**Data Model**: Plain Old Java Objects (POJOs) - These represent domain objects (Orders, Customers) in your Java EE application. These are used by all layers in your application.

This is the official [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html) documentation.

Check out these Java EE [tutorials](https://netbeans.org/kb/trails/java-ee.html) using NetBeans.

Comment: What about JMS, EJB etc? I guess without them J2EE application is just a web application with some layers.

Comment: @Hesper: JMS and EJBs are great technologies, but if you are starting from scratch I would first learn JSPs and Servlets (which came first chronologically) and are also more commonly used in smaller projects. EJBs and JMS is very useful at the highly scaled enterprise level, but I would start simpler. I currently have two paid gigs that only require JSPs and Servlets.